# How to add time and duration in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a start time and time duration. Eg: start time is 10:00pm and duration is 120minutes. I want the output like 12:00pm.Add the duration with the time.

Comment: Present some code describing what you "have" and what you've tried so far. Is what you have a DateTime object and a Duration object? Or is it strings or ints you have?

Comment: 10 PM plus 120 minutes would be 12 AM, not 12 PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 10:00pm's DataType is DateTime then  use this code.

```
  DateTime time = DateTime.now(); // Here you can get your current local time
    time.add(Duration(minutes: 120));
    print(time);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Duration class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.0/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) based on which time measurement unit you'll use.

For example, using minutes:

```
 DateTime startTime = DateTime.now();
 Duration duration = Duration(minutes: 120);

 DateTime endTime = startTime.add(duration);
 print(endTime);
```

The output with current DateTime (`14:26`) will be `2022-09-06 16:26:18.128292`.

But you could add seconds instead of minutes, or output just the time and without the day (without using the [DateFormat class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)).

```
 Duration duration = Duration(seconds: 900);
 DateTime endTime = startTime.add(duration);
 print("${endTime.hour}:${endTime.minute}:${endTime.second}");
```